# Keras neural network for detecting cats vs dogs dont predicting correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

i have been following a youtube tutorial to make a neural network predict cats vs dogs images. The tutorial ends without showing how to make predictions with any image, i have been having trouble trying to sort it out.
This is the code for the network:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

DIRECTORY = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/neural'
CATEGORIES = ['cats', 'dogs']

IMG_SIZE = 100
data = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
  folder = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, category)
  label = CATEGORIES.index(category)
  for img in os.listdir(folder):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder, img)
    img_arr = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    data.append([img_arr, label])

random.shuffle(data)

X = []
y=[]
for features, labels in data:
  X.append(features)
  y.append(labels)

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X = X/255

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = X.shape[1:], activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs = 10, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Here is the results of the training:
Epoch 10/10
647/647 [==============================] - 58s 90ms/step - loss: 0.0262 - accuracy: 0.9917 - val_loss: 1.4013 - val_accuracy: 0.7630

Now this is my try to make a prediction with the model.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras
CATEGORIES = ['Cat', 'Dog']


def image(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    new_arr = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    new_arr = np.array(new_arr)
    new_arr = new_arr.reshape(-1, 100, 100, 3)
    new_arr = new_arr/255
    return new_arr

prediction = model.predict([image('/content/drive/MyDrive/neural/test/photo-1609779361684-8196b3a0abf1.jpg')])
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.argmax()])
```

And the result i am getting are completly random. I think the problem is about resizing the image that i want to predict, but i have trying different stuff i cannot sort it out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the correct output when I tried replicating the same code using `TF 2.8`.

Please check this:
(After training the model for 10 epochs)

```
Epoch 10/10
57/57 [==============================] - 1s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 0.9822 - val_loss: 1.2132 - val_accuracy: 0.6900
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f2e6a61e290>
```

and the prediction part:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
CATEGORIES = ['Cat', 'Dog']

def image(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    new_arr = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    new_arr = np.array(new_arr)
    new_arr = new_arr.reshape(-1, 100, 100, 3)
    new_arr = new_arr/255
    return new_arr

prediction = model.predict([image('/content/GoogleDrive/MyDrive/MY WORK/cats_and_dogs_filtered/validation/cats/cat.2000.jpg')])
    print(CATEGORIES[prediction.argmax()])
```

Or can use:

```
img1=image('/content/GoogleDrive/MyDrive/MY WORK/cats_and_dogs_filtered/validation/cats/cat.2000.jpg')
prediction = model.predict(img1)
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.argmax()])
```

Output:

```
Cat
```

**Note :** It is recommended to use `tensorflow.keras` in place of `keras` as below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
```

Or use `from tensorflow import keras` to import keras

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
```

Please try again executing the same code and let us know if the issue still persists with full traceback error.